# iOS - Split Array Of CLLocations Into Just Array Of Latitudes and Longitude Strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

At the current moment in time I have an `NSMutableArray` of `CLLocations` with a whole lot of clutter for each `CLLocation` that I don't need. The log at the current moment in time is:

```
<-42.86672600,+147.32411407> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/11/14, 7:51:06 AM Australian Eastern Daylight Time-<-42.86413769,+147.32383317> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/11/14, 7:52:30 AM Australian Eastern Daylight Time-<-42.86596128,+147.32764541> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/11/14, 7:52:33 AM Australian Eastern Daylight Time"
```

How do I thin the array down so just the latitudes and longitudes are being displayed, i.e so the array comes out as:
`-42.86672600,+147.32411407/-42.86413769,+147.32383317/-42.86596128,+147.32764541`??

Cheers,
SebOH

Comment: Are you just wanting to log the items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure they're just `CLLocation` objects then...

```
for (CLLocation *location in array) {
    NSLog(@"%f, %f", location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude);
}
```

This will log out each lat and long on a single line.

If you want that specific string then...

```
NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString string];

for (CLLocation *location in array) {
    [string appendFormat:@"%f,%f/", location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude];
}

NSLog(@"%@", string);
```

This will log the exact string you put in your question.

Comment: The members of the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` are `double`s.

Comment: @JoshCaswell cool, thanks. Updated. I thought that was the case but wasn't able to check.

Comment: Yeah, what is it with the ADC search breaking every other day? Damned annoying.